# Expanded widget inside Column not expanded, instead it's got invisible

Tags: dart, flutter

I am trying to expand widget inside of Column widget but not able to make it expended.

When giving constant height to parent widget, the layout will be rendered as expected. But as I remove the constant height layout is not as expected as I want to make Listview with it and I should not give a constant height to the widget which will be used as listview item.

Below is my layout code.

```
 import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

 void main() {

 runApp(MaterialApp(
title: 'layout test',
home: Layout_test_class(),
));

 }



class Layout_test_class extends StatelessWidget {

Widget cell() {

return Container(
  color: Colors.yellow,
//      height: 200, after un commenting this will work. but i want to make it without this

  child: Row(
    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
    children: <Widget>[

      Expanded(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
          children: <Widget>[

            Expanded(
              child: Container(
                color: Colors.green,
                child: Text('apple z'),
              ),
            ),

            Container(
              color: Colors.red,
              child:Text('apple 2'),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),

      Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            color: Colors.black,
            width: 200,
            height: 200,
          ),
        ],
      ),

    ],
  ),

);

}

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
// TODO: implement build
return Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(
    title: Text('title'),
  ),
  body: Center(
   child: ListView(
     children: <Widget>[
       cell(),
     ],
   )
  ),
);
}

}
```

Below is my expected output screenshot.

[image]

Comment: you should try my answer.

Answer (score 6):

Try to wrap your Container with [IntrinsicHeight](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/IntrinsicHeight-class.html)

```
return IntrinsicHeight(
        Container(
          color: Colors.yellow
          child: ...
        )
)
```

Comment: I tried this and it worked. To be clear, you need to wrap the entire cell with `IntrinsicHeight`.

Comment: A note about IntrinsicHeight from the Flutter documentation: _This class is relatively expensive, because it adds a speculative layout pass before the final layout phase. Avoid using it where possible._

Comment: Great widget, also works as parent to a column 

Answer (score 4):

Your `ListView` needs to be inside `Flexible`. `Flexible` inside Column will set maximum height available to `ListView`. ListView needs a finite height from parent, `Flexible` will provide that based on max. space available.

```
Column(
  children: <Widget>[
    Flexible(
      child: ListView.builder(...)
    ),
    Container(
      color: Colors.red,
      child:Text('apple 2'),
    ),
  ],
)
```

Comment: amazing! BTW why `Expanded` does not work in this case?

Answer (score 3):

A nice way of doing this, it's to play with the `MediaQuery`, heigth and width.

Let me explain, if you want the widget to have the maximum heigth of a decide screen, you can set it like this:

```
Container(
height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height // Full screen size
)
```

You can manipulate it by dividing by 2, 3, 400, the value you want.

The same things works for the width

```
Container(
width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width // Can divide by any value you want here
)
```

Answer (score 2):

Actually quite the opposite, if you're planning to use this as an item in a `listView`you can't let infinite size on the same axis your `listView` is scrolling. 
Let me explain:
Currently you're not defining any `height` on your `cell()` widget, which is fine if you're using it alone. like this :

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp(
    title: 'layout test',
    home: Layout_test_class(),
  ));
}

class Layout_test_class extends StatelessWidget {
  Widget cell() {
    return Container(
      color: Colors.yellow,
      //height: 250, after un commenting this will work. but i want to make it without this

      child: Row(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
        children: <Widget>[
          Expanded(
            child: Column(
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
              children: <Widget>[
                Expanded(
                  child: Container(
                    color: Colors.green,
                    child: Text('apple z'),
                  ),
                ),
                Container(
                  color: Colors.red,
                  child: Text('apple 2'),
                )
              ],
            ),
          ),
          Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Container(
                color: Colors.black,
                width: 200,
                height: 200,
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
// TODO: implement build
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('title'),
      ),
      body: cell(),
    );
  }
}
```

But using it with a `listView` you have to define a `height`. A `listView` scrolls as long as it have some content to scroll. Right now it just like you're giving it infinite content so it would scroll indefinitely. Instead Flutter is not constructing it.

It's actually quite ok to define a global size for your container (as an item). You can even define a specific size for each using a parameter like this :

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp(
    title: 'layout test',
    home: Layout_test_class(),
  ));
}

class Layout_test_class extends StatelessWidget {
  Widget cell(double height) {
    return Container(
      color: Colors.yellow,
      height: height, //after un commenting this will work. but i want to make it without this

      child: Row(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
        children: <Widget>[
          Expanded(
            child: Column(
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
              children: <Widget>[
                Expanded(
                  child: Container(
                    color: Colors.green,
                    child: Text('apple z'),
                  ),
                ),
                Container(
                  color: Colors.red,
                  child: Text('apple 2'),
                )
              ],
            ),
          ),
          Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Container(
                color: Colors.black,
                width: 200,
                height: 200,
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
// TODO: implement build
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('title'),
      ),
      body: ListView(
        children: <Widget>[
          cell(250.0),
          cell(230.0),
          cell(300.0),
        ],
      )
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: But what about when there is dynamic height content in listview's cell/item. I can't fix the height of cell/list item.